# GLFW linking issue in makefile on OSX Lion

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, makefile, glfw

[Problems linking against GLFW in OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637797/problems-linking-against-glfw-in-osx)

I've read this already but it seems to be a different issue with me.

The command being ran in the makefile is,

```
    g++ -o main main.cpp -lglfw -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL
```

The error that I'm receiving when I run the makefile is,

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_IOMasterPort", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libglfw.a(cocoa_joystick.o)
  "_IOServiceMatching", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libglfw.a(cocoa_joystick.o)
  "_IOServiceGetMatchingServices", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libglfw.a(cocoa_joystick.o)
  "_IOIteratorNext", referenced from:
  __glfwInitJoysticks in libglfw.a(cocoa_joystick.o)
  "_IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperties", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libglfw.a(cocoa_joystick.o)
  "_IOCreatePlugInInterfaceForService", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticks in libglfw.a(cocoa_joystick.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 16):

Add `-framework IOKit` to g++ options.

Comment: Just adding some detail here: the IOKit framework is required because it's used by the recently added OS X joystick support.

Answer (score 2):

Thsnks to @Mārtiņš Možeiko, I solved part of the problem, but for me there were still few error messages :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CVDisplayLinkCreateWithCGDisplay", referenced from:
      __glfwSetVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoModes in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CVDisplayLinkGetNominalOutputVideoRefreshPeriod", referenced from:
      _vidmodeFromCGDisplayMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CVDisplayLinkRelease", referenced from:
      __glfwSetVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoModes in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [scop] Error 1
make: *** [scop] Error 2
```

To solve it, I also needed to add the CoreVideo framework.

```
-framework Cocoa -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo -framework OpenGL
```